# php processing string and echoing it out in a ul

Tags: php, html, string, html-lists, element

so i have got this string:

```
<?php
$elements = "first, second, third, fourth, fifth";
?>
```

And i'd like it to be echoed out like this:

```
<ul>
<li>first</li>
<li>second</li>
<li>third</li>
<li>fourth</li>
<li>fifth</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: Use [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and iterate over the array.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question shows absolutely minimal effort on the behalf of the questioner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it may help you issue;

```
 <?php 

$elements = "first, second, third, fourth, fifth";

$numbers = explode(", ", $elements);

echo "<ul>";

foreach ($numbers as $number) {
    echo "<li>{$number}</li>";
}

echo "</ul>";

?>
```

Comment: I can't mark this as answer yet, it says in 1 minute i can.

Comment: @Jojo01 For the future: [**Don't ask such questions!**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) SO is not a code writing service

Answer (score 1):

```
$elements = "first, second, third, fourth, fifth";
$arrayval=explode(',',$elements);
print_r($array);?>
<ul><?php
foreach($arrayval as $value){ ?>
<li><?php echo $value; ?></li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
```